# "html" is not a reserved name

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am validating a site on validator.w3.org.

It shows the following error:

> (html" is not a      reserved name)

I am using following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Any Idea, How i can fix this?

Comment: Getting a good IDE with syntax highlighting will solve this problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a closing bracket and the opening bracket as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
```

Answer (score -2):

You're missing a " />" at the end of the URL in the doctype. Hence the
validator sees something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd" Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
```

The next problem will be the XHTML  in an HTML document. Never
use that last / in empty elements in HTML, only in XHTML.

Comment: The doctype is not an element.